# Curve fit data issues

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, lmfit

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata = np.array([177,180,183,187,189,190,196,197,201,202,203,204,206,218,225,231,234,
      252,262,266,267,268,277,286,303])

ydata = np.array([0.81,0.74,0.78,0.75,0.77,0.81,0.73,0.76,0.71,0.74,0.81,0.71,0.74,0.71,
      0.72,0.69,0.75,0.59,0.61,0.63,0.64,0.63,0.35,0.27,0.26])



def f(x, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5):
    if (n1 > 0.2 and n1 < 0.8 and
        n2 > -0.3 and n2 < 0):
        return n1 + (n2 * x + n3) * 1./ (1 + np.exp(n4 * (n5 - x)))
    return 1e38

coeffs, pcov = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0 = (0.29, -0.005, 1.0766, -0.36397, 104))

ploty = f(xdata, coeffs[0], coeffs[1], coeffs[2], coeffs[3], coeffs[4])
for i in range(1, len(coeffs) + 1):
    print ('n%s = %s' % (i, coeffs[i - 1]))
```

Doesn't work properly and has this warning:

```
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)
```

But works correctly for

```
xdata = np.array([73.0, 80.0, 88.0, 93.8, 96.3, 98.5, 100.0, 101.0, 102.3,  104.0, 105.3,
                 107.0, 109.5, 111.5, 114.0, 117.0, 119.5, 121.0, 124.0])
 ydata = np.array([0.725, 0.7, 0.66, 0.63, 0.615, 0.61, 0.59, 0.56, 0.53, 0.49, 0.45, 
                   0.41, 0.35, 0.32, 0.3, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.29])
```

Lmfit doesn't work, too.

Comment: `curve_fit` is not a magic. It is not for non-smooth or bounded problems. You can try other minimization methods as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27799123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you also used `lmfit` as a tag, here is a solution using [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/installation.html). The parameter values you obtain look as follows:

```
n1:   0.26564921 +/- 0.024765 (9.32%) (init= 0.2)
n2:  -0.00195398 +/- 0.000311 (15.93%) (init=-0.005)
n3:   0.87261892 +/- 0.068601 (7.86%) (init= 1.0766)
n4:  -1.43507072 +/- 1.223086 (85.23%) (init=-0.36379)
n5:   277.684530 +/- 3.768676 (1.36%) (init= 274)
```

resulting in the following output: 
[image]

As you can see, the fit reproduces the data very well and the parameters are in the requuested ranges; there is no `if` statement required in your function.

Here is the entire code that reproduces the plot with a few additional comments:

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
import numpy as np

xdata = np.array([177.,180.,183.,187.,189.,190.,196.,197.,201.,202.,203.,204.,206.,218.,225.,231.,234.,
      252.,262.,266.,267.,268.,277.,286.,303.])

ydata = np.array([0.81,0.74,0.78,0.75,0.77,0.81,0.73,0.76,0.71,0.74,0.81,0.71,0.74,0.71,
      0.72,0.69,0.75,0.59,0.61,0.63,0.64,0.63,0.35,0.27,0.26])

def fit_fc(params, x, data):
    n1 = params['n1'].value
    n2 = params['n2'].value
    n3 = params['n3'].value
    n4 = params['n4'].value
    n5 = params['n5'].value

    model = n1 + (n2 * x + n3) * 1./ (1. + np.exp(n4 * (n5 - x)))

    return model - data #that's what you want to minimize

# create a set of Parameters
# 'value' is the initial condition
# 'min' and 'max' define your boundaries
params = Parameters()
params.add('n1', value= 0.2, min=0.2, max=0.8)
params.add('n2', value= -0.005, min=-0.3, max=10**(-10))
params.add('n3', value= 1.0766, min=-1000., max=1000.)
params.add('n4', value= -0.36379, min=-1000., max=1000.)
params.add('n5', value= 274.0, min=0., max=1000.)

# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(fit_fc, params, args=(xdata, ydata))

# write error report
report_fit(params)

xplot = np.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata), 1000)
yplot = result.values['n1'] + (result.values['n2'] * xplot + result.values['n3']) * \
                              1./ (1. + np.exp(result.values['n4'] * (result.values['n5'] - xplot)))
#plot results
try:
    import pylab
    pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'k+')
    pylab.plot(xplot, yplot, 'r')
    pylab.show()
except:
    pass
```

EDIT:

It turns out that this only works in version 0.8.3. If you use version 0.9.x you need to adjust your code accordingly; check [here](http://lmfit.github.io//lmfit-py/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-090-label) which changes have been made from 0.8.3 to 0.9.x.

Comment: Strange, it really seems that lmfit does not like you :( The above code runs fine for me; but I have no clue why you don't get any output. Do you take exactly the same code as I do; which version of lmfit are you using (I use 0.8.3)?

Comment: I replaced result.values['ni'] with result.params['n4'].value in version 0.9.2 and used exactly the same code in the other version of lmfit. Code from official site works properly.

Comment: Ok, this should not have any effect on the results. Sorry, no idea what goes wrong with your implementation then; for me it works great. You could try 0.8.3 and check whether that works. You could also try to vary the starting values since this problem is very sensitive with respect to the initial guesses.

Comment: I didn't know that we have the different versions of lmfit. And the idea that I had to look for some changes in 0.9.2 turned out to be a good idea. In 0.9.2 version `params` aren't changed by the fit. I need to use `result.params` instead of `params`.