# Scipy Curve_fit. Separate bounds for multiple parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, boundary

I am using Scipy to fit my data to a function. The function give me values for 2 parameters, in this case ***a*** and ***b***. I want to use the bound argument to limit the values these parameters can take, each have their own range of acceptable values.

Acceptable values: 15< a <50 and 0.05< b <0.2

I want to know how to implement them. The official documentation only shows how to do them for 1 parameter. This question is similiar to: [Python curve fit library that allows me to assign bounds to parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760788/python-curve-fit-library-that-allows-me-to-assign-bounds-to-parameters). Which also only tackles boundaries for 1 parameter.

Here is what i tried:

```
def Ebfit(x,a,b):
    Eb_mean = a*(0.0256/kt)                         # Eb at bake temperature
    Eb_sigma = b*Eb_mean
    Foursigma =  4*Eb_sigma
    Eb_a = np.linspace(Eb_mean-Foursigma,Eb_mean+Foursigma,N_Device)
    dEb = Eb_a[1] - Eb_a[0]
    pdfEb_a = spys.norm.pdf(Eb_a,Eb_mean,Eb_sigma)

    ## Retention Time

    DMom = np.zeros(len(x),float)
    tau = (1/f0)*np.exp(Eb_a)
    for bb in range(len(x)):
        DMom[bb]= (1 - 2*(sum(pdfEb_a*(1 - np.exp(np.divide(-x[bb],tau))))*dEb))
    return DMom

time = datafile['time'][0:501]
Moment = datafile['25Oe'][0:501]

params,extras = curve_fit(Ebfit,time,Moment, p0=[20,0.1], bounds=[(15,50),(0.05,0.2)])
```

I have also tried the following variations to see if the parenthesis was the issue:

```
 params,extras = curve_fit(Ebfit,time,Moment, p0=[20,0.1], bounds=[[15,50],[0.02,0.2]])
 params,extras = curve_fit(Ebfit,time,Moment, p0=[20,0.1], bounds=((15,50),(0.02,0.2)))
```

But I get the same error for all of these variations

> ValueError: Each lower bound mush be strictly less than each upper
>   bound.

It only works with a single bound such as:

```
params,extras = curve_fit(Ebfit,time,Moment, p0=[20,0.1], bounds=[0,50])
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: What is unclear about the `curve_fit.bounds` documentation that you don't understand how to do this? Note that the documentation mentions "2-*tuple* of array_like", so you may need to change those inner list into tuples.

Comment: @Evert Hey, Yeap I have tried that too. I still keep getting the same error though. I have edited the question to include what I have tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bounds=[[0,50],[0,0.3]])` means the second parameter is greater than 50 but smaller then 0.3. Also the first parameter is fixed at zero.

The format is bounds=(lower, upper).

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. So it should be:bounds=[[15,0.05],[50,0.2]]

Answer (score 3):

As per @ev-br suggestion. I tried the following changes for the bounds argument and it worked out great.

```
bounds=[[15,0.02],[50,0.2]]
```

So in the end, the argument give should be as follows:

```
 bounds=[[a1,b1],[a2,b2]]
```

Where **a1** is the lower limit for **a** and **a2** the upper limit for **a**. Sames goes for **b**.