# Curve_fit with bounds in Python

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a curve from a set of x,y points loaded from a .csv file.

I would like to fit a curve using a function such a way that fitted curve should start at first point and end at last point.

I am not able to understand how to give bounds in curve_fit option.

Below is the code snippet

```
def power_law(x,K,n):
    return y_data[0]+K*(pow(x,n))
params, covariance = curve_fit (power_law, x_data, y_data,p0=[500,0.2])
```

Can someone help me with suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python curve fit library that allows me to assign bounds to parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760788/python-curve-fit-library-that-allows-me-to-assign-bounds-to-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your fitted curve starts at the first point and ends at the last point of your dataset, you can modify your approach slightly. The `curve_fit` function from `scipy.optimize` allows you to fit a model to your data, but it doesn't inherently enforce that the model passes through specific points.

However, you can integrate this requirement into your model definition. Since you want the curve to start at the first point `(x_data[0], y_data[0])` and end at the last point `(x_data[-1], y_data[-1])`, you can modify your model to incorporate these conditions.

Here’s how you can adjust your power-law function:

1. **Normalize your x data** so that it spans from 0 to 1, where 0 corresponds to `x_data[0]` and 1 corresponds to `x_data[-1]`. This way, you can easily enforce the start and end points.
2. **Adjust your model** to ensure it starts at `y_data[0]` and ends at `y_data[-1]`.

Here’s an example of how you might implement this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Assuming x_data and y_data are your data arrays
# Normalize x_data to range from 0 to 1
x_data_normalized = (x_data - x_data[0]) / (x_data[-1] - x_data[0])

def modified_power_law(x, K, n):
    # Start at y_data[0] and go to y_data[-1]
    return y_data[0] + (y_data[-1] - y_data[0]) * (K * np.power(x, n))

# Initial guess for parameters
initial_guess = [500, 0.2]

# Perform the curve fitting
params, covariance = curve_fit(modified_power_law, x_data_normalized, y_data, p0=initial_guess)

# Use the fitted parameters to generate your model's predictions
fitted_y = modified_power_law(x_data_normalized, *params)

# If you need to plot or further analyze fitted_y against the original x_data, you can do so
```

In this modified function, `x_data_normalized` ranges from 0 to 1. When `x` is 0 (corresponding to `x_data[0]`), `modified_power_law` returns `y_data[0]`, and when `x` is 1 (corresponding to `x_data[-1]`), it returns `y_data[-1]`. The parameters `K` and `n` control the shape of the curve between these two points.

Comment: Looks like with this, the curve is not bound by the final point.

Comment: Thanks for reply. with the shared approach as well, the fitted curve is not bound by both points.